# Find all occurences of a specified match of two numbers in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

what i need to achieve is to get array of all indexes, where in my data array filled with zeros and ones is step from zero to one. I need very quick solution, because i have to work with milions of arrays of hundrets milions length. It will be running in computing centre. For instance..

```
data_array = np.array([1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0])
result = [3,9,13]
```

Comment: So, did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
In [23]: np.where(np.diff(a)==1)[0] + 1
Out[23]: array([ 3,  9, 13], dtype=int64)
```

Timing for 100M element array:

```
In [46]: a = np.random.choice([0,1], 10**8)

In [47]: %timeit np.nonzero((a[1:] - a[:-1]) == 1)[0] + 1
1 loop, best of 3: 1.46 s per loop

In [48]: %timeit np.where(np.diff(a)==1)[0] + 1
1 loop, best of 3: 1.64 s per loop
```

Comment: Oh I knew numpy had a diff function -- thought it was an array method though. I like the conciseness of this. +1

Comment: @PaulH, thank you! I also like (already ;) your answer - as i didn't know about `np.nonzero()` function, so I learned something new from your answer today

Answer (score 1):

Here's the procedure:

1. Compute the diff of the array
2. Find the index where the diff == 1
3. Add 1 to the results (b/c `len(diff) = len(orig) - 1`)

So try this:

```
index = numpy.nonzero((data_array[1:] - data_array[:-1]) == 1)[0] + 1
index
# [3, 9, 13]
```

Comment: I think your solution should be faster, because of `nonzero` function...

Comment: FWIW, I don't see any difference between `nonzero` and `where` on my machine (both are around 6.6 ms for 10**6 random bits)

Comment: your solution is approx. 12% faster on 10**8 array... I'll post timing...

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks a lot to all of you. Solution with nonzero is probably better for me, because I need to know steps from 0->1 and also 1->0 and finally calculate differences. So this is my solution. Any other advice appreciated .)

```
i_in  = np.nonzero(  (data_array[1:] - data_array[:-1]) ==  1   )[0] +1
i_out = np.nonzero(  (data_array[1:] - data_array[:-1]) == -1   )[0] +1

i_return_in_time = (i_in - i_out[:i_in.size] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an array filled with `0s` and `1s`, you can benefit from just comparing rather than performing arithmetic operation between the one-shifted versions to directly give us the boolean array, which could be fed to `np.flatnonzero` to get us the indices and the final output.

Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
np.flatnonzero(data_array[1:] > data_array[:-1])+1
```

Runtime test -

```
In [26]: a = np.random.choice([0,1], 10**8)

In [27]: %timeit np.nonzero((a[1:] - a[:-1]) == 1)[0] + 1
1 loop, best of 3: 1.91 s per loop

In [28]: %timeit np.where(np.diff(a)==1)[0] + 1
1 loop, best of 3: 1.91 s per loop

In [29]: %timeit np.flatnonzero(a[1:] > a[:-1])+1
1 loop, best of 3: 954 ms per loop
```